# Can't Setup Unreal Engine and Rider for Windows 11

Tags: rider, unreal-engine5, jetbrains-rider

I am tired configuring how to install Rider and setup it up to work

Firstly i installed Visual Studio 2022 with Game Development in C++ Workload

then installed Unreal Engine 5.0.3

then installed Rider 2022.2 and Activated it

then did setup rider as default in source code tab of editor preference in unreal engine

the same solution or say project made in unreal is working fine in visual studio

but i dont know why it shows project load failed

tried everything possible that i could do... like playing with build tools settings etc..

installing different .net framework installing mono etc...installing different version of msbuild etc..

i see it working for everybody... so also clean installed it again but absolutely no luck

just relieve my anxiety by simply providing a workaround to it

I tried everything possible like changing msbuild version .net sdks frameworks etc...but nothing worked

can someone share there settings if they have same setup as i described above

Answer (score 1):

The answer was simple but took me so long to figure out!!!

I have my default display language setup to Hindi the language i use in daily life...but somehow jetbrains was not able to handle the language itself and throwing error...

just changing the display setting made it work flawlessly
but yeah i lost the battle here...as i am bound to use english as a language again as display language...
before i thought i will atleast start digitizing my language by incorporating it into my workflow... but naah odds are against me...anyways will try and succeed one day.

Jai Shri Ram...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).